# Trying to use Dax to compare the Current Sales to the MTD Sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

okay so basically lets say in the month of December (Using a Slicer of Dec 1st to Dec 10th)

I want to get 2 numbers the MTD and the sales for only the current date

so in this case I want to Compare Dec 10th to the entire MTD for December

the MTD Part was easy

CY Bookings =
SUMX ( Query1, Query1[final_booked_count] )

which follows what the slicer says,

but i'm at a loss for how to tell it to pull the sales for the MAX DATE IN THE SLICER

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the last date in the slicer, you should change the context filter using CALCULATE. An easy way to do so is like follows

```
CY Bookings Last Date =
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX( Query1[date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            Query1,
            Query1[final_booked_count]
        ),
        Query1[date] = MaxDate
    )
```

If you have a model with a Date table, then the code would change to

```
CY Bookings Last Date =
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX( 'Date'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            Query1,
            Query1[final_booked_count]
        ),
        'Date'[Date] = MaxDate
    )
```